# Tiny url is stopping function from working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, webview, boolean

How can I get this function working if the link is shortened by tiny url or something similar? It seems to go through the tiny url server first thus causing google related keywords to not be read.

```
  -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest{ NSRange nameRange = [[inRequest.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"google" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if(nameRange.location == NSNotFound)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: what you want.. you want when we get google then open http://www.google.com

Comment: No, when the keyword "google" comes up when clicking a link it should be able to recognize it and open it inside the actual app in a web view. If there is no keyword "google" then it will open safari instead. But this doesn't occur when the google link is shortened by tiny url and such.

Comment: check my answer and can you provide NSLog of [inRequest.URL absoluteString]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try removing `if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked )` condition, so that you will be able to catch hold of redirects in the url. See below code.

```
 -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ([[inRequest.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"google"].location==NSNotFound){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
NSRange nameRange = [[inRequest.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"google" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if(nameRange.location == NSNotFound)
            {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
                return NO;
            }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I updated my code and seems to not open any other keyword link in safari.